# Add Item to Linq without saving it to the db

Tags: linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

Hi
I need to add an item to my current context but I need this item to be reflected when I add it without saving changes,
when I use

```
Jobs newJob=new Jobs();
context.Jobs.AddObject(newJob);
var x= from c in context.Jobs select c;
gridControl.DataSource=x;
```

Then the grid doesn't have the new value, It would have the value if I used
context.SaveChanges(); before binding the data.
Any suggestions for this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should use a intermediate data store like a list:

```
var jobs = context.Jobs.ToList();
Jobs newJob = new Jobs();
jobs.Add(newJob);
gridControl.DataSource = jobs;
```

Comment: there is no method called Add() in jobs!

Comment: there is a add method on List<Jobs>

Comment: I don't want to use a list as I need to reflect all the changes made to the context to the database at the end and I don't want to handle this by nyself.

Comment: If you make changes to the DataContext, you should Submit them, if you don't want to save them, use a List<T>

Comment: I think you should add more informations / context to the question to get better answers ;)

Comment: I have a gridview to view and also edit all the items in a SQL table,a text box to type the new item desc in it, a button to append the new item to the grid view and finally a button to save all the actions(add a new item or edit existing ones) to the database.

Comment: I'm not familiar with WinForms (i'm on asp.net) but i'm pretty sure there's tutorials explaining what you try to do, i found that (not sure it's the right for you): http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/kannagoud/4510/